# How to make a simple formula with the current attributes in LINQ Group By?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have the following object :

```
public class Report
{
     public string Code { get; set; }
     public double Budget { get; set; }
     public double Actuals { get; set; }
     public double Delta { get; set; }
}
```

With `Delta = 1 - (Budget - Actuals) / Budget`

I have a list of Report and I need to group them by Code. I did the following code :

```
        groupedReporting = reporting.GroupBy(r => r.Code)
            .Select(r =>
            new FinancialReporting
            {
                Code = r.Key,
                Budget = r.Sum(x => x.BudgetMd),
                Actuals = r.Sum(x => x.ActualsMd),
                // And the Delta...
                Delta = 1 - (r.Sum(x => x.BudgetMd) - r.Sum(x => x.ActualsMd)) / r.Sum(x => x.BudgetMd)
            })
            .OrderBy(r => r.DgId)
            .ToList();
```

I dislike this way to make 3 additional Sum in order to get the delta.

Do you know how I can avoid this and do something like "current Budget - current Actual / current Budget" in my `Select()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create an `anonymous object` and then your `FinancialReporting`. Notice i commented out the Delta calculation in the first `Select`

```
groupedReporting = reporting.GroupBy(r => r.Code)
    .Select(r =>
    new 
    {
        Code = r.Key,
        Budget = r.Sum(x => x.BudgetMd),
        Actuals = r.Sum(x => x.ActualsMd),
        // And the Delta...
        //Delta = 1 - (r.Sum(x => x.BudgetMd) - r.Sum(x => x.ActualsMd)) / r.Sum(x => x.BudgetMd)
    })
    .Select(r =>
    new FinancialReporting
    {
        r.Code,
        r.Budget,
        r.Actuals,
        // And the Delta...
        Delta = 1 - (r.Budget - r.Actuals) / r.Budget
    })
    .OrderBy(r => r.DgId)
    .ToList();
```

**EDIT**
You could always have an internal anonymous function. This way you will avoid the two `Selects`:

```
groupedReporting = reporting.GroupBy(r => r.Code)
    .Select(r =>
    {
        var Budget = r.Sum(x => x.BudgetMd);
        var Actuals = r.Sum(x => x.ActualsMd);
        var Delta = 1 - (Budget  - Actuals ) / Budget ;

        return new FinancialReporting
        {
            r.Code,
            Budget = Budget ,
            Actuals = Actuals ,
            // And the Delta...
            Delta = Delta 
        };

    })
    .OrderBy(r => r.DgId)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: +1, looks like I just copied your code in my answer :)

Comment: It might worth trying my second option.

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to set Delta to other values in other situations?

Why not declare the getter as:

```
public double Delta {
    get {
        return 1 - (Budget - Actuals) / Budget;
    }
}
```